# Flex catch line mouse events

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I have a BorderContainer with some instances of spark Line. I need to select this lines by clicking on this. But adding event mouse click listener fails. ASdoc (http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/primitives/Line.html) says that line have only activate and deactivate events. Please suggest best way to detect whether line clicked(use another line class?). I think that catching of clicks in the bordercontainer is bad solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Line's [`displayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/primitives/supportClasses/GraphicElement.html#displayObject) property to subscribe.

Comment: thanks a lot, but it raises event when the mouse clicks in rectangle that bounds the line. I want to detect when i click concrete line. See this example: http://gyazo.com/75ab847b8d99ad2fc9c927fca2d0d9e8.png. When I click on the red line, blue line handler also raises! Using hittesting?

Comment: I suggest you to draw lines using `Graphics.lineTo()`. Flex graphical primitives are mostly for declarative drawing and preferable usage is in skins. If you want to use some complicated custom graphics with interaction it is better to use custom drawings.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to ask the question: what does this act like?  In many ways, you are describing a button.  Something you can click on... probably something you would like to indicate that it can be clicked on, etc.

The behavior is there for you in `Button`, so I would consider skinning the `Button` with your line and populating your `BorderContainer` with these skinned buttons.  It would give you mouse-over abilities via states (so you can indicate to your user that the line is clickable) and it will allow you to easily add a larger hit area for the line if you need it.